# Implementing JWT with Spring security without users

Tags: spring, spring-security, jwt, spring-security-oauth2

I would like to set up an IT solution based on the Front / Back principle.
Front side I would use a technology like React, Angular and Back side I would use a technology like java spring boot to implement controller Rest.
The front will make Rest requests on the back to retrieve data.

I would like to add a security concept to the solution by implementing the JWT standard on the back. Thus the client, knowing the secret, could request a token back and could make requests by specifying the token via the header of the request.

I found several tutorials explaining how to set up this type of solutions. In particular: https://medium.com/@nydiarra/secure-...n-e57a25806c50

In this tutorial, we assume that we define somewhere (here in a H2 database) the different users of the app and their role (admin or standard).
So the front could ask a token but it would have to indicate the user and his password and the secret defined. The back looks in the database and gives a token relative to the role defined for this user.

My question is simple. Do we have to define users and roles if we want to use JWT?
What I would have liked to do is not to inform and not to store potential users and their roles.
Simply the front requests a token with the secret without giving user and the back gives a token. Which will be used later in the header of the requests.

Comment: The use case with Json Web Tokens is that an auth provider (for ex Auth0) provides a jwt based on a user's credentials. And using that token you request data from the backend application, including the jwt in the Authorisation header. And then, in you backend app you decode and verify the signature of the token and based on some role (included in the payload of the token) you authorise the request to perform some operations.

Comment: Ok I see, thanks for your post